# writing into file (std::ofstream) in a loop writes last line only

Tags: c++, file, parsing, file-io, ofstream

I'm using this code to extract certain part of each line of a text file:

```
std::ifstream file( "infile.txt" );
std::string in1, out1;
int blockNumber = 0;

while( getline( file, in1 ) ) 
{   
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while( i <= blockNumber )
    {   
        n = in1.find_first_of("(", n + 1); 
        i++;
    }   
    out1 = in1.substr( n + 1, ( in1.find_first_of(")", n) - n - 1) );  
    ofstream fmatch ("solo_matches.txt",ios::out);
    fmatch.close();
    fmatch.open("solo_matches.txt");
    fmatch << out1;
    fmatch.close();
}
```

But when I run the code, the result is not as I expect it to be. Only the last string is being written to the file. If I use this instead:

```
 std::cout << out1 << std::endl;
```

I get the exact output I need. I do not understand what is the difference.

Comment: So what is the input that you use to get that output?

Comment: Why do you construct `ofstream`, then `close` it and then `open` it again?

Comment: `fmatch.close();
fmatch.open("solo_matches.txt");` surely can be completely removed, as these two lines do eactly the oposite of the previous line.

Comment: where is `}` for the first `while` ?

Comment: And it looks like you're closing the stream after every output.  You should open it once, then output everything you want to it, then close it.

Comment: Do you mean what is inside infile.txt ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move file open and file close operations outside while loop:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file( "infile.txt" );
    std::string in1, out1;
    int blockNumber = 0;
    std::ofstream fmatch ("solo_matches.txt",std::ios::out);

    while( getline( file, in1 ) ) 
    {   
        int n = 0;
        int i = 0;

        while( i <= blockNumber )
        {   
            n = in1.find_first_of("(", n + 1); 
            i++;
        }   
        out1 = in1.substr( n + 1, ( in1.find_first_of(")", n) - n - 1) );  
        //fmatch.close();  //you don't need this
        //fmatch.open("solo_matches.txt"); //you don't need this
        std::cout << out1 << std::endl;
        fmatch << out1 << std::endl;
    }   
    fmatch.close();
}
```

And replace

```
fmatch << out1;
```

with

```
fmatch << out1 << endl;
```

if you need `cout` and `fmatch` agreement.

Comment: great solution, thanks! In this way, I get the exact output I need.

Answer (score 5):

Well, ofstream probably overwrites existing contents every time you open it. I mean, every time you open file, write pointer will be placed at the begninning, so even without `ios::trunc` flag new data written into that file will overwrite existing contents.

To solve the problem, stop reopening ofstream twice for every line of text. File open operation can be slow.

Either that, or try using `ios::app` flag.

Comment: +1 `ios::out|ios::ate` should also work (been awhile since i've done it though).

Comment: @alby76 Please "accept" the answer that helped you the most by clicking the checkmark next to their answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::ofstream fmatch("solo_matches.txt", ios::out);
fmatch << ...;
fmatch.close();
```

opens the file, rewrites its content and saves it upon closing the stream. To append the content at the end of the file, you can use `ios::app` flag:

```
std::ofstream fmatch("solo_matches.txt", ios::out | ios::app);
```

or yet even better, instead of reopening the file in every iteration:

```
while (...) {
    construct ofstream
    write to file
    close ofstream
}
```

you could do:

```
construct ofstream
while (...) {
    write to file
}
close ofstream
```

Also note that this line:

```
out1 = in1.substr( n + 1, ( in1.find_first_of(")", n) - n - 1) );
```

relies on the correct format of the input, it would be safer to check the return value of `find_first_of`:

```
std::size_t pos = in1.find_first_of(")", n);
if (pos != std::string::npos)
{
    out1 = in1.substr( n + 1, pos - n - 1 );
    ...
}
```

Comment: it works now with "ios::app", thanks! Interesting to know, but i'm sure of the input bacause "infile.txt" is a log file and I verify it in another process.

Comment: @alby76: yet for the sake of maintainability & reusability of this code in the future, it is usually better to minimize the constraints of your code and rely on as few things as possible :)